# Android - Respect device orientation settings (don't rotate if rotation lock is on)?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I'm having trouble getting my app to respect the device's orientation lock settings.  It is still rotating the activity even if I've got the device itself locked to portrait/landscape orientation.

I am not implementing any "configChanges" parameters in the manifest. What could I be missing here?

Comment: Even if the device rotation is locked, your app still rotate?

Comment: Yes. Even with rotation lock enabled in the Android settings, the app still will change orientation when the device is rotated.

Comment: It's strange. Try to test it in another device/emulator maybe the problem is on the device, otherwise post the AndroidManifest and  activity code.